# Why Visual Studio display O like this?

Tags: visual-studio

Why is there a point under "O", as you can see in the following picture ? I'm using consolas.

[image]

Things are normal in vim :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's a thing on the O. You can see the `_O_RAW` don't have one in the middle. I think it's your editor trying to suggest a change like on the `_`.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over it you will see that it tells you that "Macro can be converted to constexpr". [Example](https://i.imgur.com/otDn98v.png)